# How to use jquery variables in ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to access a javascript variable in ruby it showing an undefined variable error.

I tried to access the variable x in the ruby code "phone#{x}"

var x = 1;

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
  e.preventDefault();
  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed

    x++;

    $(wrapper).append('<div class="sampleclass"><%= f.label :"phone#{x}", class: "control-label col-md-3" %><div class="col-md-8"><%= f.text_field :"phone#{x}", class: "form-control" %><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div></div>'); //add input box
  }
});
```

I expect the output phone#{x} to phone2

Comment: Ruby happens on the server and javascript on the client. You need AJAX to communicate between them.

Comment: In append you passing a string, so use  "phone"+x+"[...rest of string]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectations are completely wrong - Ruby (ERB) is executed on the server while this javascript is executed later on the client.

There is no way that you can read a javascript variable on the fly in a javascript erb template. Its just an advanced version of string interpolation, which renders javascript just the same way as it does HTML. It does not actually execute the resulting code.

A better alternative is just to use ERB to produce a template string and modify the elements with javascript.

```
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
  var $template = $('<div class="sampleclass"><%= f.label :phone", class: "control-label col-md-3" %><div class="col-md-8"><%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div></div>');
  e.preventDefault();
  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    x++;
    $template.find('label').text("phone " + x);
    $template.find('input').attr(name: "phone_" + x);
    $(wrapper).append(template); //add input box
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use rails tags inside the *.js file unless it is something like *.js.erb

I can figure out what you are trying to accomplish here. You have to use the HTML to make the whole element on the go.

You can use something like this.

```
    $(wrapper).append('<div class="sampleclass"><label class="control-label col-md-3"> Phone'+ x +' </label><div class="col-md-8"><input type=text name="phone'+ x +'" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div></div>');
```

Adding a sample of how it would look with your code.

[image: sample of code]